# AWS Cli doesn't include specific command switch even though the documentation shows that it should, any idea how to solve it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

AWS have announced 5 days ago that they now support VPC peering over different regions.

Source:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/

In regard to the AWS Cli command which helps you achieve that peering connection, please check this link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-vpc-peering-connection.html

You will see that the command has been extended and now can get a new switch "[--peer-region value]" but after upgrading my aws-cli to the latest version, the switch is not included there.

These are the switches I have:

```
NAME
       describe-vpc-peering-connections -

DESCRIPTION
       Describes one or more of your VPC peering connections.

       See also: AWS API Documentation

SYNOPSIS
            describe-vpc-peering-connections
          [--filters <value>]
          [--dry-run | --no-dry-run]
          [--vpc-peering-connection-ids <value>]
          [--cli-input-json <value>]
          [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

The AWS Cli version I have installed is:

```
aws-cli/1.14.2 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.4.0 botocore/1.8.6
```

The Python 3.6 aws-cli also lacks this switch.

Can it be that the official AWS documentation has been updated but the AWS Cli not?

Anyone else bumped into this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `create-vpc-peering-connection` has the option `--peer-region` on my system.

You show the command syntax for `describe-vpc-peering-connections`. This command does not have the `--peer-region` option.

Are you confusing the two commands together?